# deep_clone in ruby on rails instead of clone ( shallow copy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, clone

I have a recommended item for one particular client and i have to duplicate that particular recommended item entry for other clients too,So I was thinking to deep_clone of that item to that other clients , so that when that item entry is deleted from one client it doesn't get removed from other clients too (basic deep copy concept)

but how to do deep_copy in ruby on rails and is that right approach to go for deep_clone instead of clone ?

here is my code

```
@item = CuratedItem.find(params[:data_curated_id])   
@duplicate =Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(@item) )
```

this marshalling does the same thing as clone, it gives the same copied parameters, so what the difference, is clone does a deep copy too ?

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you tried so far? What error are you getting? Unless I'm missing something, I think you can just use `new_record = old_record.dup`.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, would recommend you to go through this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TomLord check again i have edited the post

Comment: *but how to do deep_copy in ruby on rails* -- Use a gem: https://everydayrails.com/2015/07/29/deep-cloning.html *is that right approach to go for deep_clone instead of clone* -- If you clone, then changes in one client's recommendation will appear in another client's recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `deep_cloneable` gem, https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable

It works well for creating related sets of ActiveRecord objects, and you can specify which relations you do and do not want to clone, with smart behavior around saving them. The only gotchas I've found with it related to the order in which the cloned records get created, which may be different from the original order. So if you've got any subtle bugs around `order` attributes, deep_clone can be tricky.